Why do PCs and gaming laptops require graphics cards when phones can render without them?
Can you explain why PCs and gaming laptops have large graphics cards with high power usage when phones can render without them?

Even PCs can render without large graphics card (dedicated). They'll use integrated graphics of their CPU. Just a comparison search for Integrated GPU vs Dedicated GPU will help you understand why PCs and gaming laptops have large graphics cards.

All modern phones have some sort of GPU built into their design.

In simple terms, raw performance.
There are many PCs and laptops with graphics built into the processor, and they do fine for most "normal" tasks. We call these GPUs "integrated graphics" or, if you are AMD and are trying to distance yourself from calling it "integrated graphcs" as it was historically quite poor performance, an APU (Accelerated Processing Unit) which is basically a CPU and GPU smushed together.
The thing about a dedicated graphics card is that it can offload graphics processing entirely from the CPU.
In phones and PCs with integrated graphics the CPU and GPU have to share memory bandwidth.  When the GPU is drawing things for the screen or getting textures for a game the CPU is sat there waiting. They can both do their jobs in time, but not quite as efficiently as if they has their own memory.
For a lot of tasks and lower end games that is fine. But sometimes you need more.
That's where "dedicated" graphics cards come in. They have their own memory. It requires the CPU to fill it up to begin with, but after that step it can do all the work without holding up the CPU.  As a result you can run a dedicated graphics card harder and faster as you can guarantee it will have the maximum bandwidth available all the time.
Dedicated GPUs also have their own cooling system. The don't have to limit the amount of power they can run at to so that they don't overheat the CPU, and the CPU doesn't have to run slower to avoid overheating the GPU.
The result is that dedicated GPUs can be a lot more powerful than the GPU in a phone or an integrated GPU.
Phones can look good, but if you compare the graphics with a top end dedicated GPU you will see a difference. The dedicated card can probably do higher resolutions, better lighting, better textures and at higher frame rates.
We have all these options to cater for people with different needs. You want the best graphics at 8K running at 120Hz? then you spend money on getting a heavy duty PC with expensive graphics cards. You want something to draw pretty pictures on a small screen where no one can see the fine detail? Then you get a mobile phone GPU that is built into the processor and is just about "good enough".
